# Ошибка SOAP looks like we got no XML document.Как исправить?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, soap, веб-служба

Добрый вечер.

Начал разбираться с SOAP,набросал простенький сервис новостей и клиент под него и получил ошибку.

Что есть:

- сервис новостей,находится в папке news (все это крутится на OpenServre`e)
- soap-server,находится в папке news/soap
- wsdl файл news.wsdl,находится в папке news/soap
- soap-client,находится в папке localhost

Что я делаю:

Запускаю OpenServer,перехожу на localhost - вылетает

> Операция Client вернула ошибку: looks like we got no XML document

Проверил кодировки и BOM-символы,все в порядке.

soap-server.php

```php
<?php
require "../class/NewsDB.class.php";
class NewsService extends NewsDB{
  /* Метод возвращает новость по её идентификатору */
  function getNewsById($id){
    ........................................
  }
  /* Метод считает количество всех новостей */
  function getNewsCount(){
    ........................................
  }
  /* Метод считает количество новостей в указанной категории */
  function getNewsCountByCat($cat_id){
  ...................................................
  }
}
// Отключение кеширования wsdl-документа
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
// Создание SOAP-сервера
$server = new SoapServer("http://news/soap/news.wsdl");
// Регистрация класса
$server->setClass("NewsService");
// Запуск сервера
$server->handle();
```

soap-client.php

```php
<?php
$client = new SoapClient("http://news/soap/news.wsdl");
try{
// Сколько новостей всего?
  $result = $client->getNewsCount();
  echo "<p>Всего новостей: $result</p>";
// Сколько новостей в категории Политика?
  $result = $client->getNewsCountByCat(1);
  echo "<p>Всего новостей в категории Политика:$result</p>";
// Покажем конкретную новость
  $result = $client->getNewsById(5);
  $news = unserialize(base64_decode($result));
  var_dump($news);
}catch(SoapFault $e){
  echo 'Операция '.$e->faultcode.' вернула ошибку: '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

news.wsdl

```html
<?xml version ='1.0' encoding ='UTF-8' ?> 
<definitions name='News' 
    targetNamespace='http://news'
    xmlns:tns=' http://news'
    xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' 
    xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' 
    xmlns:soapenc='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' 
    xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/' 
    xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'> 

  <message name='getNewsByIdRequest'> 
    <part name='id' type='xsd:integer'/> 
  </message> 
  <message name='getNewsByIdResponse'> 
    <part name='item' type='xsd:base64Binary'/> 
  </message> 

  <message name='getNewsCountResponse'> 
    <part name='count' type='xsd:integer'/> 
  </message>

  <message name='getNewsCountByCatRequest'> 
    <part name='cat_id' type='xsd:integer'/> 
  </message> 
  <message name='getNewsCountByCatResponse'> 
    <part name='count' type='xsd:integer'/> 
  </message>


  <portType name='NewsPortType'> 
    <operation name='getNewsById'> 
      <input message='tns:getNewsByIdRequest'/> 
      <output message='tns:getNewsByIdResponse'/> 
    </operation>
    <operation name='getNewsCount'> 
      <output message='tns:getNewsCountResponse'/> 
    </operation>    
    <operation name='getNewsCountByCat'> 
      <input message='tns:getNewsCountByCatRequest'/> 
      <output message='tns:getNewsCountByCatResponse'/> 
    </operation>    
  </portType>

  <binding name='NewsBinding' type='tns:NewsPortType'> 
    <soap:binding style='rpc' transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http'/> 
    <operation name='getNewsById' /> 
    <operation name='getNewsCount' />
    <operation name='getNewsCountByCat' />  
  </binding> 

  <service name='NewsService'> 
    <port name='NewsPort' binding='NewsBinding'> 
      <soap:address location='http://news/soap/soap-server.php'/>
    </port> 
  </service> 
</definitions>
```

Где,я ошибся? Что исправить?

Признателен за уделенное время.

Comment: Было бы очень хорошо, если бы вы нас не пересылали на третьи ресурсы.

Comment: Да, было бы неплохо попробовать сформулировать вопрос покороче и без километровых листингов. Ссылка на toster.ru, который завтра может сдохнуть - не ОК.

Comment: @Etki Обновил вопрос,убрал ссылку,сократил код...посмотрите,пожалуйста,буду признателен за любые идеи.

Comment: @dred Обновил вопрос,убрал ссылку,сократил код...посмотрите,пожалуйста,буду признателен за любые идеи.

Comment: В каком файле и строке ошибка?

Comment: @Etki в soap-client.php...в какой строке не скажу,т.к. даже если убрать блок try-catch'а,оставить "$client = new SoapClient("http://news/soap/news.wsdl");"..то все равно выскакивает ошибка.Я правильно понимаю,что с wsdl,где-то ошибся?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавте

```
ob_clean();
ob_start();
```

Перед

```
$server->handle();
```